# Live/bootable Kali linux from partitioned USB Hard Drive (Mac/OS X)?

Tags: osx, kali-linux, live-usb, macintosh, bootable

I'm trying to boot Kali on a Mac from an external drive's partition (GUID Partition Map). The drive has 3 partitions, and I have data on the other 2 (that won't fit on my internal drive). I want bootable Kali on the 3rd one, without affecting the other 2.

I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install), but I'm guessing that `dd` only works for entire drives (rather than partitions). I used `dd … of=/dev/disk2s2` to targent a specific partition, and the command did something (the partition got wiped), but it was unmountable.

I also looked into Linux USB Builder, and unetBootin, but the former only detects the entire drive, and the latter not at all (presumably it has to be formatted FAT32).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So you want to have an external harddrive that has 3 partitions but only one of the partitions has kali on it that you can boot into.

Comment: DD will also replace all the partitions on the drive so you should never 'dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sda1' because the iso already has a partition table. You can see it by doing an 'fdisk -l file.iso'. If you want kali linux running on a specific partition, you should follow their official guide and or manually mount the iso and copy it's contents from the squashfs image into the partition you wish to use but keep in mind your need to adjust kernel and bootloader to fit your setup.

Comment: Yes, CitizenZero, that's exactly what I want to do.
@likewhoa: the official guide is only for entire drives, it seems (that's the guide I linked in the question). I would welcome instructions to adjust the kernel/bootloader, if you think that will get me a bootable partition.

Comment: @Khashir have you tried selecting the 'manual' option during the installation section that deals with installing to disk? I assume you will be able to manually select the partition for kalinux to install to.

Comment: @likewhoa: I haven't gotten to that point because I don't have installation media. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: (@likewhoa: As in, the point of my question is to use the partition as installation media).

Comment: @Khashir you can manually mount the iso, then mount the squashfs file and you copy those files into your partition but then you have to setup the bootloader and possibly kernel. I am just making an educated guess here since I never used kalinux but being a person that builds livecds often, I know what they mostly consist of and how to manipulate them.

Comment: @likewhoa: could you link to a good resource for finding my way around the kernel and bootloader, in this situation? I'll be happy to read and write up an answer, if I get it working. Currently installing FUSE - squashfs

Comment: Linux sea is a good beginner read.

Comment: @likewhoa: For the life of me, I haven't been able to compile squash-fs: I keep getting the following error:

./configure: line 13582: syntax error near unexpected token `pkgconfig_XZ,liblzma,'
./configure: line 13582: ` PKG_CHECK_MODULES(pkgconfig_XZ,liblzma,'

I double-checked the PLATFORMS and README files, and I believe I installed all required packages. I've submitted a support request, let's see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

First use `DD` to make the usb bootable with kali. Then use `gparted` and use the remaining to create the other partitions on your device. Then, you should put `boot` flag on the partition with kali.

Comment: I thought of that, but `dd` will erase the data on the other two partitions =(.

Comment: If they are small copy them in a folder on your computer

Comment: No can do, as I stated in the question.